# How do I invoke the MIDL compiler to generate a .TLB file (type library) from an .IDL file?

Tags: winapi, com, idl, typelib, midl

I am struggling with something seemingly super-simple: I'd like to use the MIDL compiler to generate a type library (`.tlb` file) from a `.idl` file. However, I just can't get MIDL to generate a `.tlb` file.

This is my `Foo.idl`:

```
import "unknwn.idl";

[object, uuid(400075B9-4BD6-45A5-B8B7-9DA0CF7B9B13)]
interface IFoo : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT DoFoo([in] int arg, [out, retval] int *result);
}
```

This is how I invoke the MIDL compiler:

```
midl Foo.idl /tlb Foo.tlb
```

Which writes the following output to the console:

```
Microsoft (R) 32b/64b MIDL Compiler Version 7.00.0555
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Processing .\Foo.idl
Foo.idl
Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\unknwn.idl
unknwn.idl
Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\wtypes.idl
wtypes.idl
Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\basetsd.h
basetsd.h
Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\guiddef.h
guiddef.h
```

The MIDL compiler produces three files: `Foo.h`, `Foo_i.c`, `Foo_p.c`… but no `Foo.tlb`. Am I misunderstanding something, or what has gone wrong here?

Comment: Only stuff defined or referenced in `library` block is placed into a TLB file. Further, interfaces you want to place into a TLB should be `dual` or `oleautomation` or `dispinterface`. A TLB format can only accurately represent an automation-compatible interface. `int` is not an automation type - make it a `long`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Thank you for your suggestions. Where do you guys take all that good knowledge from!? Could you by chance recommend a resource where I could read up on the _"a TLB format can only accurately represent an automation-compatible interface"_ bit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The .idl file requires a `library{}` block before it will generate a type library.  Inside this block you'll need to declare the types that need to be present inside the library.  A normal library only has `coclass` definitions in the library section, midl automatically injects any interfaces that the coclasses use.

Getting just the interface requires moving it inside the library block:

```
[
  uuid(34DC0E7C-37C1-41C1-B3FD-1755A0396308),
  version(1.0),
]
library MyLibrary
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    [object, uuid(400075B9-4BD6-45A5-B8B7-9DA0CF7B9B13)]
    interface IFoo : IUnknown {
        HRESULT DoFoo([in] long arg, [out, retval] long *result);
    };
};
```

Use your own uuid, version number and name for the library.  The `importlib` voodoo ensures that the definitions for IUnknown and GUID don't get embedded in the type library as well.

Comment: `Getting just the interface requires moving it inside the library block` A declaration, as in `interface IFoo;`, of an interface defined outside the block should be sufficient.