# I'm a bit stuck with Dynamic Virtual Channels in Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, terminal-services

I'm in the process of converting code for Dynamic Virtual Channels in RDS (aka Terminal services) from C++ to Delphi based on the https://github.com/earthquake/UniversalDVC/tree/master/UDVC-Plugin in C++. This requires several classes for registering the client plugin and I found definitions in `tsvirtualchannels.h` and `.idl` on my Windows system at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um` .

Unfortunately the `.idl` file does not contain a type library, so I couldn't build a type library `.tlb` file and import that so I've been recreating it manually in Delphi.

Embarcadero use a `.ridl` file, similar but not quite the same as idl files. One of the attributes in the `.idl` file is `cpp_quote("string")`. For example

```
cpp_quote("EXTERN_C __declspec(selectany) const IID IID_IWTSListenerCallback = {0xA1230203, 0xd6a7, 0x11d8, {0xb9, 0xfd, 0x00, 0x0b, 0xdb, 0xd1, 0xf1, 0x98}};")
[
object,
uuid(A1230203-d6a7-11d8-b9fd-000bdbd1f198),
oleautomation,
helpstring("interface IWTSListenerCallback")

]
interface IWTSListenerCallback : IUnknown
```

Ridl doesn't support cpp_quote, so I'm unsure how to deal with these.

Comment: Looks a bit like Delphi's [`{$HPPEMIT string}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/HPP_emit_(Delphi)).

Comment: By a complete coincidence, I sent you an email yesterday! Does that directive work in a .ridl file?

Comment: Didn't see the email yet, will take a look. No, that only works in Delphi.

Comment: Yes that did it. If you want to make this comment an answer, I'll make it the accepted answer.

Comment: Comment converted to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`midl.exe` (from Windows SDK) should be able to generate a `tlb` from the `idl` file.

If there's no library definition in the `idl` file, you can add one yourself, as explained by Hans Passant in his answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269119/how-do-i-invoke-the-midl-compiler-to-generate-a-tlb-file-type-library-from-an).